# How to replicate Python 2 style len() in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to replicate Python 2 style `len()` in Python 3, as it relates to unicode strings.

In Python 2 the `len()` of a unicode string is its on-disk bytes size. for example: `len("애정")` returns **6**. In Python 3 `len()` returns the number of characters in the string, the example returns **2**.

`sys.getsizeof()` is not the solution, because that gets the size of the Python object in-memory, not the size the object would be if it was written to the disk.

Comment: In your python 2 example, that is not a unicode string, that is a byte string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can encode it to `utf8` like below.

```
>>> len('애정'.encode('utf8'))
6
>>>
```

Comment: `.encode()` also works, since UTF-8 is the default. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode